# why Runtime.instance always giving me error

Tags: agents-jade

hey everyone i'm new at #jade and now i'm trying to write #main class and i have error at "#Runtime rt=new Runtime.instance();" this line ,i added all external jars for jade but still have this problem what dose that mean pLiz help

import jade.core.Runtime;
public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Runtime rt=new Runtime.instance();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`instance` method is a static method that returns the instance of `Runtime` class. you needn't use operator `new`. That is, try to use `Runtime rt=Runtime.instance();`